# Three JS match object rotation with joystick

Tags: javascript, three.js

I’m trying to implement an onscreen joystick to control a 3D avatar’s movement.

1. The joystick is from Nipplejs
   https://github.com/yoannmoinet/nipplejs
2. The perspective camera is fixed in place and continuously lookAt at the moving avatar
3. After the character moves a certain distance, the camera will jump to a position behind the character
4. I’m using joystick’s radian position for the avatar’s Y rotation

However when I push the joystick 90 degrees, the 3D avatar doesn’t move forward, instead it rotates and moves to the right.

And when the avatar rotates towards a different direction, pushing the joystick 90 degrees results in the avatar again changing to a different direction.

I’ve included a drawing showing the fixed joystick and the above situation.

How can I have the avatar’s direction always match the joystick’s rotation / direction?

Thank You!

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you sure the avatar is rotating then translating, or is it simply translating 90 degrees from where you think it should without a rotation?

Comment: Man, we'll need code for this. What's your code so that we can at least debug it.

Comment: @HumanTarget Yes I'm first rotating the model before translating it.